# How to secure JMS server by MAC list in Weblogic?

Tags: security, jms, weblogic

Is there any body knows if weblogic can secure JMS server by limit MAC addresses?

For example, I want to make WLS reject the JMS request which is not sent from specified MAC list.
Is that possible to implement?

Thanks,
Xianyi.Ye

Comment: I think you will have to set up a separate firewall. Weblogic does not contain this feature.

Comment: Thanks, I already found the solution. refer to:http://weblogicissuesolutions.blogspot.jp/2011/05/steps-to-configure-weblogic-connection.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you blocking with MAC address or IP based on that link?

Comment: by IP Address. Not sure whether WLS security rule support MAC or not. But limit access by IP Address is feasible.